# Getting mqrc 2080 while trying to browse messages in DLQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to browse messages in a DLQ and I get the 2080 error.

Please share your expertise on this issue.

```
1:root@hostname:/root # ./amqsbcg SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE QM.ABCDEFG

AMQSBCG0 - starts here
**********************

 MQOPEN - 'SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE'

 MQGET 1, failed with CompCode:1 Reason:2080
 MQCLOSE
 MQDISC1:root@hostname:/root # mqrc 2080

      2080  0x00000820  MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `dmpmqmsg` utility that comes with MQ V8 and above.

The following invocation as an example...

```
dmpmqmsg -m QM.ABCDEFG -i SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE -f myfile.txt
```

This will give you a hex dump of the message after the MQMD is dumped out. amqsbcg would also only give you a hex dump of the message, so in both cases you are still going to have to pick your DLQ reason code out from the hex message.

Comment: I would try it on MQ8 but the server has still MQ7.1.0.8 version. Thanks for a work around of dmpmqmsg.

Comment: Get a client install with V8 then use it from there.

Comment: @MoragHughson strangely I noted that `dmpmqmsg` is not included in the Redist client, it does include other handy tools like `dmpmqcfg` and `runmqsc`.  Do you know of `dmpmqmsg` is included in the full client?

Comment: You're right to ask @JoshMc I'm actually not sure - just hoping. I would have expected `dmpmqmsg` to live wherever `dmpmqcfg` lived since they are two halves of the same problem - grab your config and grab your messages. Perhaps an RFE is needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

amqsbcg is a sample MQ program that is included with MQ when you install the development tools.  The source for amqsbcg (amqsbcg0.c) is located in the /opt/mqm/samp/ directory.

If you look at the source, you will see on line # 137:

```
#define    BUFFERLENGTH  65536  /* Max length of message accepted */
```

Therefore, any message larger than 65536 bytes will cause MQ to return RC of 2080 (MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED) which your messages appear to be larger than 65536 bytes.

Therefore, you have some choices:

1. Take a copy of amqsbcg0.c, update it with a larger value,
   compile & link it
2. Use the browse feature of MQ Explorer
3. Use a vendor tool like [MQ Visual Edit](http://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) to
   view the Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: I tried the way which you mentioned. I edited the file, saved it. But I'm not sure what is "compile". If it is a simple process, can you please explain here.

Comment: @Rinak - "compile and link" is the term used to describe building some 'C' language code (which is what sample amqsbcg0.c is) into an executable that can run (which is what amqsbcg.exe is). What programming language are you familiar with?

Comment: @Morag Hughson: Unfortunately I do not know any programming languages.

Comment: @Rinak - that is a shame. I was planning to translate 'compile & link' into whatever verbiage was used for the programming language you were familiar with. Suffice to say, a program written in code generally starts life as a text file like amqsbcg0.c that you saw and edited. However it cannot be run directly from this text file for certain programming languages. The text file needs to go through a process to turn it into an executable program, amqsbcg.exe in this case. That process is refered to here as 'compile & link'. The process is done using a 'compiler'. Suggest you look these terms up.

Comment: Edited the answer above to include MQ Explorer. @Rinak do you have that too installed?

Comment: @MoragHughson I'm not sure why you added MQ Explorer.  MQ Explorer's browse feature will only display the first 1000 bytes of the message.  The user's message on the DLQ is greater than 65536 bytes.

Comment: Hi Roger - I didn't realise MQ Explorer failed with a truncate in that situation - I thought it accepted a truncated message and then you would at least be able to see the DLH reason code which (I assume) is the main thing they are after. I also thought it might be something @Rinak might have available since he is not kitted out with a compiler.

Comment: @MoragHughson : We don’t have MQ explorer installed.

Comment: @Rinak, do you have any MQ admin or monitoring tools installed at all?

Comment: @MoragHughson : We don’t use any GUI tools like MQ explorer to browse the messages. All we use is only amqsbcg to view the messages. I’m the MQ admin.

Comment: @Rinak - well, as you can see, you're going to need to look into some tools to get you beyond what the supplied samples can do. The supplied samples were not intended to be a monitoring solution. They are samples to teach you how to write IBM MQ applications.

Comment: @Rinak - thought of one more solution - see new answer posted.

Comment: @MoragHughson : I will report the issue to PMR team and will see what they can suggest. Well, as you said, I will have to setup some monitoring tools in our environment to make life easier. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @Rinak - before you go the PMR route - try the new suggestion I just posted.